# Scroll Collection view to the top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a following collection view. When the user scrolls the view up, I want the collection view to go all the way up. Similarly, when it is scrolled down, I want it to come back to its original position.

I have a uiview and imageView above the collectionview.

[image]

Now, If this was a tableview, I would have used header. How do i achieve this behavious. I am out of Ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is the sub-class of `UIScrollView` so you can achieve what you want is just by the scrollview `delegate` method and the constraints of your `UIView` and `UIImageView` upon the UICollectionView.

Here I am going to give you one example to achieve this with scrollview delegate.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == collectionView{
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
                    self.constTopTagHeight.constant = 175 // Your UIView and imageview constraints adjust.  
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            else{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
                    self.constTopTagHeight.constant = 0 // Your UIView and imageview constraints adjust.
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, `constTopTagHeight` is the view i am having on the top. RIght? If I apply this to the scrollview, it is only shrinkiung my topview and not scrolling the collectionView all the way to the top. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes constTopTagHeight is the top view height constraint. You just need to manage that in above scrollview delagate method.